# Möbius transformation with infinity in both the $w$-plane and $z$-plane.

Tags: mobius-transformation

I want to find the Möbius transformation which brings $f(0)=\infty$, $ f(\infty)=0$, and $f(5)=i$. If I use the formula

\begin{equation}
\frac{(w-w_1)(w_2-w_3)}{(w-w_3)(w_2-w_1)}=\frac{(z-z_1)(z_2-z_3)}{(z-z_3)(z_2-z_1)}
\end{equation}

then I get a cancellation of the $w$-variable. That would give just another complex number, $z=5i$. But what does this mean?

Thanks

Comment: Forget that formula for a second. Which Möbius transformations map $0$ to $\infty$ and $\infty$ to $0$?

Comment: $|z|>0$ would be a good example?

Comment: ?? – $|z|> 0$ is not a Möbiustransformation.

Comment: A Möbius transformation is a *function* of the form $T(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ with complex constants $a, b, c, d$.

Comment: I thought that |w|>0 has an infinite number of points on the w plane, so infinity would be there too. I consider your example. So  $T(0)=\frac{b}{d}=\infty $ and $T(\infty)=\frac{a}{c}=0$, then solve the two equations

Comment: This gives, along with the third condition: a=c=0, $d\infty=di$. But this is no equation, and does not give any transformation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132510/discussion-between-viola-player-and-martin-r).

Comment: @ViolaPlayer There are several elementary mobius transformations you can examine by setting most of the constants $a,b,c,d$ to zero. See if you can find one of those that takes zero to infinity.

Comment: You can use the ansatz $f(z)=a/z$ because you know $1/z$ swaps $0$ and $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula
$$
\frac{(f(z)-w_1)(w_2-w_3)}{(f(z)-w_3)(w_2-w_1)}=\frac{(z-z_1)(z_2-z_3)}{(z-z_3)(z_2-z_1)}
$$
can only be applied if all $z_j$ and $w_j$ are complex numbers, i.e. not $\infty$. The general formula is
$$
 (f(z), w_1, w_2, w_3) = (z, z_1, z_2, z_3)
$$
where $(z, z_1, z_2, z_3)$ is the [cross-ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio) of the numbers $z, z_1, z_2, z_3$, that is the value of $z$ under the Möbius transformation which maps $z_1, z_2, z_3$ to $0, 1, \infty$, respectively.

If $z, z_1, z_2, z_3$ are all (distinct) complex numbers then their cross-ratio is
$$
(z, z_1, z_2, z_3) = \frac{(z-z_1)(z_2-z_3)}{(z-z_3)(z_2-z_1)} \, .
$$
If one of the $z_j$ is equal to $\infty$ then the corresponding formula can be obtained by a limiting process. As an example, for $z_1 \to \infty$ we get
$$
(z, \infty, z_2, z_3) = \frac{z_2-z_3}{z-z_3} \, .
$$
Similarly,
$$
(z, z_1, \infty, z_3) = \frac{z-z_1}{z-z_3} 
$$
and
$$
(z, z_1, z_2, \infty) = \frac{z-z_1}{z_2-z_1} \, .
$$

---

In your case we need the solution for
$$
 (f(z), \infty, 0, i) = (z, 0, \infty, 5) \, .
$$
Using the above formulae this translates to
$$
\frac{0-i}{f(z)-i} = \frac{z-0}{z-5} \iff \boxed{f(z) = \frac{5i}{z}} \, .
$$

---

Of course one could have obtained that result with an educated guess. A Möbius transformation exchanges the points $0$ and $\infty$ if it is of the form $T(z) = a/z$ for some non-zero constant $a$, and the condition $f(5)=i$  gives $a=5i$.

Comment: Thanks Martin!! I will write this down.

Comment: I retried your method, and I get only to $z/(z-5)$. But from there to  $5i/z$ I don't know how you do it. How did you do it, if this is all equal to $w$? In fact, I got $w=/frac{5i}{z}+i+1$, which is the same as you got, just shifted.

Comment: @ViolaPlayer: Try it again. If you solve the equation $\frac{0-i}{w-i} = \frac{z-0}{z-5} $ for $w$  then you'll get $w = \frac{5i}{z}$.

Comment: Got it, used erroneously the identity $-i=1/i$, but I got $w=-\frac{5i}{z}$